# PHP - Download and save file to specific directory

Tags: php, export-to-csv, symfony-3.4

I have a code that downloads a file with data that I am exporting to .csv format but it does not save it into specific directory in my Symfony project that I defined.

Any help?

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($results) {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
        $rows= $this->get('my.service')->getMyData();
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            fputcsv($handle, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    });

    $fileName = 'user_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv';
    $rootDir = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
    $dir = $rootDir . '/../var/upload/' . $fileName;

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='. $fileName);

    return $response;
```

Comment: You can not specify what path anything gets stored under on the _client_, only the user can decide that.

Comment: _“but it does not save it into specific directory in my Symfony project that I defined”_ - sounds like you don’t want a _client-side_ download to begin with, but store a file on the server side …? In that case, the code you have is wrong for the task to begin with.